# Spring Boot - Thymeleaf template

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-boot-actuator

I am using Spring Boot 1.2.7 and Thymeleaf.

All the html pages are inside the `src/main/resource/templates` folder and everything works fine when I say `return "<viewName>"` inside the controller.

Now, I would like to use different folder structure for AngularJS.

Would like to move the pages to some other folder, say `webapps/pages`.

Tried configuring the resolver as below,

```java
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver getViewResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("webapps/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Still not working... Am I missing any other config or should I not use Thymeleaf in this case?

pom.xml for your reference,

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure one `TemplateResolver` inside the `application.properties` (or `application.yml`) file, if you do not want to use the standard configuration. You can find a list of available options in [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

Then introduce a new `@Configuration` for additional `TemplateResolver`s:

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    @Autowired
    private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver resolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();

        resolver.setPrefix("webapps/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
        resolver.setOrder(templateEngine.getTemplateResolvers().size());

        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(resolver);
    }

}
```

Comment: I would like to have few files in templates and few files under webapps/pages. Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. However it should be possible. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Still it doesnt work. I have added /templates in application.properties spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5

and the above config file. But /webapp./pages/ doesnt work

Comment: Did you configure the second TemplateResolver exactly as shown above? Note that the prefix has no preceding classpath:/ or slash. I tried this snippet and it works for me.

Comment: Yes, i do have the same thing.

Comment: Yes, i do have the same thing.
My folder structure is 
/src/main/resources/
    - pages/*.html
    - templates/*.html
/src/main/webapp/
   - index.html
I have /templates/ in application.properties and /pages/ in Config java file. I tried with webapp/ for htmls under webapps and pages/ for htmls under pages.

Comment: You don't have to specify '/templates/' in the properties file. If you do so you have to write 'classpath:/templates/', nevertheless. For the second resolver set the prefix to 'pages/'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93513/discussion-between-user1578872-and-steffen-kreutz).

Comment: Your directory webapps/pages/ is under src/main/resources directory? By default, Thymeleaf search his templates here.